# Corrupted Memory when dealing with Array of Structs

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I have a struct of values looking like this:

```
typedef struct SName
{
    char abc[10];
    float xyz;
} TName;
```

To fill this I got a function which basically creates a TName and fills the values with strncpy or assigning values to the floats. Looking like this:

```
TName fillOne(){
     TName* myObj = (TName*)malloc(sizeof(TName));
     //fill values
    return *myObj;
}
```

This works like a charm, checking the return value with an breakpoint in XCode show that all values are filled in correctly.
Now I want to create an Array of TNames:

```
TName *arrayOfTNames(){
    TName fullArray[100];
    *fullArray = *(TName*)malloc(100*sizeof(TName));
    //Now loop 100 times and do fullArray[count]=fillOne();
   return fullArray;
}
```

Checking with XCode on a sample with less than 100 iterations I now have just what I want, but in the 95 slot I have random memory values which should not be there.
Two questions now:
1. is it right, that I never use free until after I used the results I got from arrayofTNames()?
2. How to properly handle the return value of arrayOfTNames?

Comment: Why would you declare an array of size 100 and then `malloc` for 100 elements and assign the array to it? Reserve memory on the stack *or* allocate on the heap, but don't do both for the same variable...

Comment: `TName fillOne()` --> `TName *fillOne() ... return myObj;`

Comment: No! `return fullArray;` returns a pointer to a local variable that goes away when you leave the function.

Comment: ...even if it seems to work like a charm, you've lost the pointer returned by `malloc()` on exit from `fillOne()`, so you can't `free()` the memory.

Comment: @yrk please do not change your question in response to comments. Rolled back.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *have to* use malloc to allocate memory. You can just use your structs.

```
TName fillOne(){
   TName myObj;
   //fill values
  return myObj;
}
```

will also work, and return a copy of `myObj`.

Returning an array isn't possible, so you have to either put the array in another struct (and return that), or return a pointer to allocated memory:

```
TName *arrayOfTNames(){
    TName* fullArray = malloc(100 * sizeof(TName));
    //Now loop 100 times and do fullArray[count] = fillOne();
   return fullArray;
}
```

And then don't forget to `free` the memory when you are done with the array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're doing:

- Create a 100 element array on the stack
- Assign to the first element of that array The first TName-sized chunk of freshly heap-allocated memory
- Assign to each element of the array (on the stack) a TName element on the heap, freshly allocated (and initialized)

That's almost surely not right.

You probably want something like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct SName {
  char abc[10];
  float xyz;
} TName;

TName* arrayOfTNames()
{
  TName *fullArray;
  fullArray = (TName *) malloc(100 * sizeof(TName));
  for(int i=0; i<100; ++i){
    strcpy(fullArray[i].abc, "whatever");
    fullArray[i].xyz=1.0;
  }
  return fullArray;
}

int main()
{
  TName* array = arrayOfTNames();
  for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    printf("%s;%f\n", array[i].abc, array[i].xyz);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
TName fullArray[100];
```

allocates 100 elements of type `TName` on the *stack* - and this will be destroyed as soon as the function exits.

However, the `malloc`-statement in the next line allocates the elements on the *heap*, which survives the function exit. If you want to create the array inside a function and use it outside, you have to use the heap variant. For example like that:

```
TName *arrayOf100TNames(){
  TName *fullArray;
  fullArray = (TName*)malloc(100*sizeof(TName));
  // Now loop 100 times and fill each individual struct
  return fullArray;
}
```

Note that filling each individual struct is not possible like in your comment `fullArray[count]=fillOne()`. Instead, you could either directly write each element, or e.g. use `memcpy` to copy the output of `fillOne()` into an array element.

Comment: Note that you can copy one `struct` to another in just the same way that you can copy, say, one `int` to another. You don't need `memcpy()`.